# Find solution for PDE that looks like the equation of a sphere

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given the partial differential equation

$$\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \right)^2 = C$$

where $C \geq 0$.

Some properties of this equation that I have noted:

- Partial rather than ordinary
- Non-linear
- Non-exact
- Non-homogenous?
- Not sure how separation of variables would work...
- If I take $C = r^2$ then this equation looks like the equation of a sphere.

How do I go about finding a solution to this differential equation?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eikonal_equation

Comment: An easy solution $$f = ax + by + cz$$ with $a, b, c$ such that $a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} = C$.